# "There's already data in (Pivot Table Name)"

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I get this error message sometimes when refreshing or remaking a pivot table:

> There's already data in [SheetName][PivotTableName]". Do you want to replace it?

It's hard to reproduce, but I think it has to do with data (pivot or non-pivot) adjacent to the pivot table.

Does anyone know what causes this error?